# After performing automatic login in Java, How I can open the result in the original website?

Tags: java, authentication, automation, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying an automated login using Java, I am able to log and retrieve data from the page displayed after successful login.

But I do not see how the result displayed in the original web page, i.e. after login, redirect content.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

// add header
post.setHeader("Host", "cursa.me");
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
post.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "es-ES,es;q=0.8");
post.setHeader("Cookie", getCookies());
post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
post.setHeader("Referer", "http://cchsur.cursa.me/califications?locale=es");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use chrome build-in debugger by pressing F12 then navigate to Network tab, check in 'Preserve log' and login manually. You will see what happened.

Comment: I've checked and logged manually, subsequent analysis That I Could Achieve an automatic login, the problem I have is That That It shows me the HTML code. What I want is to redirect to the URL, for the user to continue navigating the original URL.

Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You can see the response headers of your send request, it will have a header named 'Location', that is the url browser will redirect to. If it is not what you want, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe I'm not very clear, I'll try again.

What should the system?

1. Allow login
2. After the login, redirect to a specific section (Refer)

What do you have?

The login and redirection, the redirection is possible by setting "Referred" on request HttpPost.

What is the problem?

Do not know how to redirect to the original URL.

example:

Original URL and login: cursa.me
Automatic login: mywebsite.com

After login in, mywebsite.com content (loginOk.cursa.me) is shown in:
mywebsite.com (source)

Ideally:
Redirection ---> oginOk.cursa.me

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: how about javascript: window.location = 'loginOk.cursa.me';

Comment: Yes, it's the idea.
However, the redirection is not trivial, requiring a cookie of session and modify HTTP Referer attribute.

All this, I repeat what I have. But I'm not capable of addressing the server URL, but am only able to enter automatically and get the source code.

Comment: *Part 1: Actually, I am not the coder of your project so I dont know what is exacly problem with you. But I had this project that is login as a request to server (same same as you wrote on code), get the response, get the location header on response header, analyze it to get parameters and then build another url with those parameter to use it as login command to another website. (Request -> Webservice -> Get login token -> Login using token).

Comment: * Part 2: Before I created the above flow, I have to analyze what actually happened while I login by using F12 tab Network on chrome. I have to go step by step as records, read header to see what did my machine send? and the response for that request (response header also merged on bellow of request header, looks same same as request header). Then I build ways: the first I build way same as network tab's flow and after that I changed to do the first and last step because it have relation on Location header of response headers.

Comment: *Part 3: I don't clearly your question so I tell you a story, hope this might can help you. Sorry, I'm for not help you clear this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comments are very helpful and very good.
However, I can not fix the problem.

You know any way I can manually send POST request?

It would be a great help.

Comment: *Part 1: Based on you target website. Usually, websites use form with post method.
How do you want to manually send post request?
By html webform or java appication?
I recommend you first create a form with html content as a FAKE login form and make sure it work

Comment: *Part 2: <form method="post" action="http://u.xtv.vn/openlogin/mlogin">
<input type="text" name="redirecturl" value="http://mu2.vn/account/callback" />
<input type="text" name="gameid" value="Game_MU" />
<input type="text" name="clientip" value="127.0.0.1" />
<input type="text" name="Login.UserName" value="myaccountid"/><input name="Login.Password" value="myaccountpwd"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

Comment: *Part 3: Write java app using send request header to do what exacly that form did (beware of content-length header node). You will know the step: read from F12 chrome => FAKE using html form => FAKE using java application

Comment: *Part 4: sorry I forget this: F12 to Network tab and see the 'mlogin', see it request and response headers

Comment: Actually I want to do is similar to this example "2. HttpsURLConnection Example" http://goo.gl/I4alOh . But I do not want to see in console code, I want to open the section that was previously authenticated in the browser.